# How to Secure CloudMonitor API Call using API Signature on Alibaba Cloud ECS

Tags: alibaba-cloud-ecs

CloudMonitor APIs in Alibaba Cloud ECS belong to the RPC type and can be called CloudMonitor APIs by sending HTTP requests.

I am calling **QueryMetricList** to query the monitoring data of ECS instance using this command.

```
http://metrics.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/?Action=QueryMetricList
&EndTime=2017-05-17+11%3A30%3A27
&StartTime=2017-05-17+11%3A20%3A27
&Period=60
&Dimensions=%7B%22instanceId%22%3A%22i-abcdefgh123456%22%7D
&Timestamp=2017-03-22T09%3A30%3A57Z
&Project=acs_ecs_dashboard
&Metric=cpu_idle
```

How to authenticate each API request through the API signature.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate API request via the API signature you need **Access ID** and **Access Key Secret**.

Let me consider the **Access ID** and **Access Key Secret** as **Key** and **Value** respectively:

Your request before adding the signature:

```
http://metrics.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/?Action=QueryMetricList
&EndTime=2017-05-17+11%3A30%3A27
&StartTime=2017-05-17+11%3A20%3A27
&Period=60
&Dimensions=%7B%22instanceId%22%3A%22i-abcdefgh123456%22%7D
&Timestamp=2017-03-22T09%3A30%3A57Z
&Project=acs_ecs_dashboard
&AccessKeyId=Key
&SignatureMethod=HMAC-SHA1
&Metric=cpu_idle
```

AccessKey Secret is `value`, and the key used for HMAC calculation is `value&`. Then the signature value is calculated.

Add the signature value to the above API Request.

For instance, Let me consisder `signature = "sdsdfasdfa"` then the request will be:

```
http://metrics.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/?Action=QueryMetricList
&EndTime=2017-05-17+11%3A30%3A27
&StartTime=2017-05-17+11%3A20%3A27
&Period=60
&Dimensions=%7B%22instanceId%22%3A%22i-abcdefgh123456%22%7D
&Timestamp=2017-03-22T09%3A30%3A57Z
&Project=acs_ecs_dashboard
&AccessKeyId=Key
&SignatureMethod=HMAC-SHA1
&Signature="sdsdfasdfa"
&Metric=cpu_idle
```